# Unable to use geoip packages in Remix

Tags: geoip, remix.run

I have tried using both `geoip-lite` and `fast-geoip` packages in Remix but they prevent the route from rendering.

```
const geoip = require('geoip-lite');

const geoip = require('fast-geoip');
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be?

Comment: "*but they prevent the route from rendering*" - What does this mean? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No errors and the console logs from the server side are  output. 

I have worked around it by moving the geoip lookup code out of the route and importing it